# Display different widgets based on radio button selection

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project that is going to use tkinter. I was wondering if there was any way to display a different set of widgets based on a radio button selection and it update as soon as it is clicked

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Do a little research and try to come up with a solution, and when you come to a more specific question, come back and ask. As written, this question is simply too broad. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, put your sets of widgets in different tkinter Frames and show/hide them on demand as you select different radio buttons.